# У какого-нибудь есть проект NavigationDrawer с tutecentral.com?

Tags: android

Кто-нибудь поможет мне найти полный исходный код этого http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ проекта. Я не могу скачать его, из-за битой ссылки. Я провёл впустую 3 дня с этим проектом, но ничего не получилось. Я не могу получить никакого результата. Пожалуйста, если у кого-нибудь есть полный проект и он не против им поделится, я буду очень счастлив. Большое спасибо!

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться [библиотекой Майка Пенза](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer), принципиально именно этот проект?